# ebay url image rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite url for images, original image url is like **http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/d/w225/pict/370850474463.jpg** and I want to redirect urls on my site domain url like **http://thumbs.mydomain.com/d/w225/pict/370850474463.jpg** to the original.

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule thumbs2.domain.com/d/w225/pict/121233069297.jpg thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/d/w225/pict/121233069297.jpg [R,L] 
 and
RewriteRule http://([A-Za-z0-9-]+).domain.com$ http://([A-Za-z0-9-]+).ebaystatic.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**any help please
thanks**

Comment: What have you tried so far? The rewriting module has an excellent documentation. Is there anything you do not understand?

Comment: i'd tried many things so far but could not succeeded. can u please give me an example for this?

Comment: @Raheel if you provide some examples of what you've tried we can explain why they didn't work and help you find a solution

Comment: RewriteRule http://thumbs2.domain.com/d/w225/pict/121233069297.jpg    http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/d/w225/pict/121233069297.jpg [R,L]
can i write url in this way? just for testing purpose

Comment: i also tried this: 
**RewriteRule http://([A-Za-z0-9-]+).domain.com$ http://([A-Za-z0-9-]+).ebaystatic.com/$1 [R,L]**

Answer (score 0):

OK, please have a read of the manual, it explains how all this works.

The examples you give don't work as the `RewriteRule` [matches the requested URL path](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (not the hostname).

You can try this:

```
# Match the requested hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} thumbs.domain.com
# Check that the request ends in an image extension and redirect the whole request
RewriteRule \.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i write this rule:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} thumbs1.oshopy.com/

RewriteRule \.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
and trying to getting images from this: 
**http://thumbs1.oshopy.com/d/w225/pict/121233069297.jpg**

Comment: There is no DNS record for thumbs1.oshopy.com, so the Internet doesn't know how to visit the server that handles requests for that domain name. You'll need to set up a DNS record and configure your server to handle requests for that domain name first before this works.

Comment: ooopppss but how should i configure DNS? i don't have any idea about DNS. please give me some.

Comment: You'll need to talk to someone in your organisation who administers the domain name/server to find that out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43323/discussion-between-raheel-and-jon)